# using if to compare answers and call function

Tags: python, function, input

I'm trying to compare two answers, if the answer to question is "e", i need it to call a function CheckID, this function is connecting to database in some server and extracting some information. I can connect to database but the issue is it is not calling the function after answering the question, it shows me that 'e' is not defined !! I tried to define it by adding e = CheckID() but still it doesn't call the function. Please help me to achieve that or let me know what I'm doing wrong

here is my code:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

question = input("Type 'e' to Check Existing Id, or 'a' to add Account Id ?   ")

if question == 'e':
    CheckID()

else:
    AddID()


def CheckID():

    acc = input("Type ID ")  

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="", user = "", password = "", host = "", port = "")
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('select "AccountID","Zip" from "Account" where "AccountID" =  %s', (acc,))

    ans =cur.fetchall()
    ans1 = {}

    for AccountID in ans:

        if len(Zip) != 3:       
            Zip = '111'
            print(AccountID, Zip)


        else:
            print(AccountID, Zip)

def AddID():
    print "Thank you for using our script"

ask()
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
enter code here Type 'e' to Check Existing Id, or 'a' to add Account Id ?   e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final7.py", line 4, in <module>
    question = input("Type 'e' to Check Existing Id, or 'a' to add Account Id ?   ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Comment: You're running the file in Python 2, where `input()` is the same as `eval(raw_input(...))`. Run your program as such: `python3 final7.py`

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked well. after changing to raw_input, and placing functions above the question! thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue resides with which Python version you're using. I operate in Python 3.6 and the code worked properly. In Python 2.x,

```
input
```

was defined as

```
raw_input
```

So just run your code in 3.6 or update your "input" to "raw_input".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are running your script in python 2 and not python 3. In Python 2, `input()` is the same as `eval(raw_input(...))`.

Run your program as such: `python3 final7.py`